# Check if value column A in B python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new column 'check' with the following condition:

- 'Suppression total' and 'Sup-SDM'.

OR

- Suppression partiel and Franc SUP - Geisi

**Dataframe**:

| Date of event | Type | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-08 | Sup_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression totale |
| 2021-12-15 | Modif_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Creation |
| 2021-12-31 | Sup_EF - SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression totale |
| 2021-12-17 | Modif_EF - Franc SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-17 10:50:40.0-Suppression partiel |

**Desired output**:

| Date of event | Type | Info | Check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-08 | Sup_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression total | Correct |
| 2021-12-15 | Modif_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Creation | Fail |
| 2021-12-31 | Sup_EF - SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression total | Fail |
| 2021-12-17 | Modif_EF - Franc SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-17 10:50:40.0-Suppression partiel | Correct |

**Code**:

```
df['check'] = np.where((df.Type.str.contains('SUP - SDM') & df.Info.str.contains('Suppression total') & (df['Date of event] in df.Info))
                       | (df.Type.str.contains('Franc SUP - Geisi') & (df.Info.str.contains('Suppression partiel'))&& (df['Date of event] in df.Info))),'correct','fail')
```

**But error  'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test if exist substring per 2 columns use list comprehension:

```
m = [a in b for a, b in zip(df['Date of event'].astype(str), df['Info'])]
df['check'] = np.where((df.Type.str.contains('SUP - SDM') & df.Info.str.contains('Suppression total') & m) |
                       (df.Type.str.contains('Franc SUP - Geisi') & df.Info.str.contains('Suppression partiel') &m),'correct','fail')

print (df)
  Date of event                           Type  \
0   2021-12-08             Sup_EF - SUP - SDM    
1   2021-12-15           Modif_EF - SUP - SDM    
2   2021-12-31           Sup_EF - SUP - Geisi    
3   2021-12-17   Modif_EF - Franc SUP - Geisi    

                                        Info    check  
0   2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression totale  correct  
1             2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Creation     fail  
2   2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression totale     fail  
3  2021-12-17 10:50:40.0-Suppression partiel  correct
```

Comment: Thanks your answer but when i applied it has TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. I checked type of Infos: object and date of event: datetime64. So i don't know why 'float' is here?

Comment: @Cherrycherry - Try `m = [a in b for a, b in zip(df['Date of event'].astype(str), df['Info'])]`